# useDelimiter won't recognize vertical bar

Tags: java, delimiter

useDelimiter will not recognize vertical bar but will recognize other characters.

This does not work:

```
scan.useDelimiter("|");
```

This does work:

```
scan.useDelimiter(",");
```

Rest of Code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner("12,d,  |, f | ");

// initialize the string delimiter
scan.useDelimiter(",");

// Printing the delimiter used
System.out.println("The delimiter use is "+scan.delimiter());

// Printing the tokenized Strings
while(scan.hasNext()){
    System.out.print(scan.next());
}

// closing the scanner stream
scan.close();
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the vertical bar (Pipe character) by doing;

```
scan.useDelimiter("\\|");
```

Comment: or [pattern.quote(String s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks that was exactly it.

Comment: When I tried that, scanner converted the pipe-delimited string into a comma-delimited string.  Now I have to do a split on the result to get the individual elements from the file.  Makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me with

```
sc.useDelimiter("\\|");
```

and

```
sc.useDelimiter("[|]");
```